# Update json values by their key name

Tags: mysql, sql, json

### Background

I have a MySQL table with a json field. That field stores a array of json objects.
The order is not always the same, so i need to get the path to a key for updating operations.

```sql
Entity | ID, jsonField |

Entity | 1,  [{clazz:'health', hp:'100'},{...},{...}] // Health the first index
Entity | 2,  [{...},{...},{clazz:'health', hp:'25'}] // Health at the last index
```

### The question

How do i get the path to the `.hp` field for every single entity in order to update its value ? Or... a bit more precious, how do we set the `.hp` field to, lets say 100, in every entity jsonField array, regardless of its position ?

Comment: You have a JSON array of objects that each have the same fields, a `clazz` and a `hp`? Why not just store these as rows in a second table, with a `clazz` varchar column and a `hp` int column? Then it would be easy to do practically anything you want with them.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks, but thats not possible. Each entity has 0-n different unknown objects inside that field... thats why the dynamic structure matters here.

Comment: Use regular expression - this will be more simple and fast.

Comment: @Akina Thanks, im gonna look into them ! Can you provide a example ? ^^

Comment: Please provide CREATE TABLE script and INSERT INTO with some sample data (3-5 rows), and show desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to find the index for the `hp` key in the array (if it exists), and then use that result to make the update:

```
with recursive cte(id, js, ind, f) as (
   select e.id, e.jsonfield, 0, json_extract(e.jsonfield, '$[0].hp') is not null from entities e
   union all
   select c.id, c.js, c.ind+1, json_extract(c.js, concat('$[', c.ind+1, '].hp')) is not null from cte c where not c.f and c.ind+1 < json_length(c.js)
),
inds(id, ind) as (select id, ind from cte where f)
update entities e join inds i on e.id = i.id set e.jsonfield = json_set(e.jsonfield, concat('$[', i.ind, '].hp'), '100');
select * from entites;
```

Output:

| entity | id | jsonfield |
| --- | --- | --- |
| entity | 1 | [{"hp": "100", "clazz": "health"}, {"x": "1"}, {"y": "2"}] |
| entity | 2 | [{"x": "1"}, {"y": "2"}, {"hp": "100", "clazz": "health"}] |